# set of n objects, and show k-element subsets in python

Tags: python, subset, element, sage

Suppose you have a set of n objects, and you want to list its k-element subsets (that is, its
subsets with exactly m elements) solved by **Recursive functions** without using `list(itertools.combinations)`
for example `k_subsets({1,2,3},2 )`
 show the

```
[{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}]
```

Comment: do you mean subsets with exactly k elements?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: yes , subsets with exactly k elements Finn

Comment: I know the algorithem, algorithm combinations
inputs
 S, a set of n objects
 m, the number of objects you’d like to pick from S, with m  n
outputs
 the subsets of S of size n
do
if jSj = m
let result = fSg
else
let result = ;
for s 2 S
let U = Sns
add combinations(U, m) to result
return result Scott Hunter

Comment: What exactly is your question? It seems you forgot to write the second half. Your first sentence starts with "suppose you want to do this and that", but then it just stops.

Comment: @mkrieger1 you will understand the question read carefully.

Comment: @AminAmin now check i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be the code of `combination` using recursion, and this will give you all the subsets of given list and the subsets of desired length.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
s = 2
unique = []
def combination(set):
    if set == []:
        return [[]]

    sub = combination(set[1:])
    # This will give you all the subsets of given list and This is also the return variable of the function.
    all_combination = (sub + [[set[0]] + x for x in sub])
    ########################################################
    # This for loop will give you a subsets of desire length.
    for i in range(len(all_combination)):
        if int(len(all_combination[i])) == s and all_combination[i] not in unique:
            unique.append(all_combination[i])
    #########################################################
    return all_combination

print(combination(l1))
print(unique)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Fine, answer is true but not a exact answer of my questions. I want the code that just appear these '[{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}]' not all. Just because we work with subset not ordered pair. For example [{1,1}] is not acceptable because we used 1 once or {1,2} and {2,1} is the same.

Comment: @AminAmin now check i have updated my answer. This is according to your desire.